# Customised the facebook friends invite email format in openinviter

Tags: email, facebook, joomla

I am developing a web application on joomla cms. In which i am using open inviter for send invitation  to Gmail , AOL and Facebook ID. Gmail and AOL receiver get mail in proper html format which i am sending. like this

[image]

But **for facebook account** same mail displaying like this

It is showing html format in html code.

[image]

Can anyone explanin me how can i get facebook mail in proper html format like Gmail or AOL?
Is this any default setting in facebook for sending mail by third party web application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the text version of the HTML. I'd imagine Facebook doesn't allow HTML in there as it needs to control what it shows to it's users. Can you provide a 'Click to view this in a browser' link maybe?

Comment: Are you sure facebook doesn't allow html? Can't I send same email with html format(with proper images and css) on facebook id.

Comment: You'd need to check with Facebook unfortunately.